# Program crashes almost immediately after starting

Tags: c#, exception, crash, clr

On my dev machine, I'm using VS2012. It's a WPF program, targeted for .NET 4.5. It runs just fine for me on the dev machine. However, when I test it on another computer, it will start, hang, and then crash with a window saying "MyApp has stopped working". Click to view details, I see an XML log, which has this information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
-<WERReportMetadata>
 -<OSVersionInformation>
 <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion> 
 <Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build>
 <Product>(0x30): Windows 7 Professional</Product> 
 <Edition>Professional</Edition> 
 <BuildString>7601.18113.x86fre.win7sp1_gdr.130318-1533</BuildString> 
 <Revision>1130</Revision> 
 <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor> 
 <Architecture>X86</Architecture> 
 <LCID>1033</LCID> 
 </OSVersionInformation> 
 -<ParentProcessInformation>
 <ParentProcessId>2600</ParentProcessId>
 <ParentProcessPath>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</ParentProcessPath> 
 <ParentProcessCmdLine>C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE</ParentProcessCmdLine> 
 </ParentProcessInformation> 
 -<ProblemSignatures> 
 <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType> 
 <Parameter0>myApp.exe</Parameter0>
 <Parameter1>3.3.5.5</Parameter1> 
 <Parameter2>51682570</Parameter2>
 <Parameter3>mscorlib</Parameter3>
 <Parameter4>4.0.30319.17929</Parameter4> 
 <Parameter5>4ffa561c</Parameter5> 
 <Parameter6>43c4</Parameter6> 
 <Parameter7>105</Parameter7> 
 <Parameter8>System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse</Parameter8>
 </ProblemSignatures> 
 -<DynamicSignatures> 
 <Parameter1>6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48</Parameter1>
 <Parameter2>1033</Parameter2> 
 <Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22> 
 <Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23> 
 <Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
 <Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25> 
 </DynamicSignatures>
 -<SystemInformation>
 <MID>5C6F71F8-85F7-4E38-AB94-44B953155C30</MID> 
 <BIOSVersion>6.00 PG</BIOSVersion> 
 </SystemInformation> 
</WERReportMetadata>
```

Now, I had assumed that the issue was in the mscorlib, since that's under "Problem Signatures". However, I noticed that that file exists, and it is the appropriate version number. There is also a txt log file which consists of the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> <DATABASE> <EXE NAME="myApp.exe" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="myApp.exe" SIZE="61440" CHECKSUM="0x5F150F1F" BIN_FILE_VERSION="3.3.5.5" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="3.3.5.5" PRODUCT_VERSION="3.3.5.5" FILE_DESCRIPTION="My Program" COMPANY_NAME="From Home" PRODUCT_NAME="My Program" FILE_VERSION="3.3.5.5" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="My Program.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="My Program.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © From Home 2012" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="3.3.5.5" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="3.3.5.5" LINK_DATE="04/15/2013 16:26:23" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/15/2013 16:26:23" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00002204bc03a42c8bfbb302394dd279b63d42740dac" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="app.dll" SIZE="40448" CHECKSUM="0x5E9750F" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.4849.27478" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.4849.27478" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.4849.27478" FILE_DESCRIPTION="DailyReport" COMPANY_NAME="From Home" PRODUCT_NAME="DailyReport" FILE_VERSION="2.0.4849.27478" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="DailyReport.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="DailyReport.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright From Home © 2013" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.4849.27478" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.4849.27478" LINK_DATE="04/11/2013 21:15:57" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/11/2013 21:15:57" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="000085f170a19e6b5e8e946feeb760e0d88925760057" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="lua5.1.dll" SIZE="325960" CHECKSUM="0xC69B4921" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x56FB6" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" LINK_DATE="08/09/2010 18:57:16" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/09/2010 18:57:16" EXPORT_NAME="lua5.1.dll" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000280fac9cf711d93c95f6b80ac97d89cf5853c096" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="MySql.Data.dll" SIZE="382976" CHECKSUM="0xF6E33CCD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.6.4.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.6.4.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.6.4.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="MySql.Data.dll" COMPANY_NAME="Oracle" FILE_VERSION="6.6.4.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="MySql.Data.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="MySql.Data.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2004, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x6CE8E" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.6.4.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.6.4.0" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 19:19:22" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 19:19:22" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000db0146c05339a80db023c1ae16d0e1642872da7f" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="NLog.dll" SIZE="388096" CHECKSUM="0xE71161C5" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="NLog for .NET Framework 4" COMPANY_NAME="NLog" PRODUCT_NAME="NLog v2.0.0.2000" FILE_VERSION="2.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="NLog.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="NLog.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) 2004-2011 by Jaroslaw Kowalski" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x6B2F2" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="07/18/2011 06:26:53" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/18/2011 06:26:53" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="000012f50065f5b3b21552ae45cfbdcc1dfff5326c5e" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="PresentationFramework.dll" SIZE="2040296" CHECKSUM="0xE53B2864" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.0.30319.17929" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.0.30319.17929" PRODUCT_VERSION="4.0.30319.17929" FILE_DESCRIPTION="PresentationFramework.dll" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® .NET Framework" FILE_VERSION="4.0.30319.17929" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="PresentationFramework.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="PresentationFramework.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1FC9DA" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.0.30319.17929" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.0.30319.17929" LINK_DATE="07/09/2012 06:24:56" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/09/2012 06:24:56" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000ad06ce5b4e6b7b0807f3d3bdf0662e37c201e3cc" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="System.Data.SQLite.dll" SIZE="1025024" CHECKSUM="0x479B453D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.84.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.84.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.84.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Data.SQLite Interop Assembly" COMPANY_NAME="Robert Simpson, et al." PRODUCT_NAME="System.Data.SQLite" FILE_VERSION="1.0.84.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="SQLite.Interop.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="SQLite.Interop" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Public Domain" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xFA458" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.84.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.84.0" LINK_DATE="01/09/2013 19:24:08" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/09/2013 19:24:08" EXPORT_NAME="System.Data.SQLite.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00006f3f7b6a03d9042a08f8bdb7b92f6fb542ecd5e5" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll" SIZE="183296" CHECKSUM="0xA5ED2385" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.84.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.84.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.84.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Data.SQLite for LINQ" COMPANY_NAME="http://system.data.sqlite.org/" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Data.SQLite" FILE_VERSION="1.0.84.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Public Domain" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2CCE1" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.84.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.84.0" LINK_DATE="01/09/2013 19:25:56" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/09/2013 19:25:56" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000c8970ba6a5e8b84a0bb3ecb69021741b40622bae" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="uninstall.exe" SIZE="1344512" CHECKSUM="0x36E8F08F" BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.1.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.1.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="9.1.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Setup Application" COMPANY_NAME="Indigo Rose Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Setup Factory Runtime" FILE_VERSION="9.1.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="suf_rt.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="suf_rt" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Runtime Engine Copyright © 2012 Indigo Rose Corporation (www.indigorose.com)" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.1.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.1.0.0" LINK_DATE="06/14/2012 15:50:03" UPTO_LINK_DATE="06/14/2012 15:50:03" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000b717fd548382064189c16cb94dda28b1967a5712" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" SIZE="507392" CHECKSUM="0xD474338B" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.7.4644.13122" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.7.4644.13122" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.7.4644.13122" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit" COMPANY_NAME="Xceed Software Inc." PRODUCT_NAME="Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.7.4644.13122" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Xceed Software Inc. 2010-2012" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x7EBB6" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.7.4644.13122" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.7.4644.13122" LINK_DATE="09/18/2012 12:17:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/18/2012 12:17:25" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00001a006d37fd32f2cc0e93f7ef0ce89d1a4e436568" PROGRAM_ID="0000e1913cb9b12c018ba3d96e7a81891fca0000ffff" /> </EXE> <EXE NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="KernelBase.dll" SIZE="293376" CHECKSUM="0x70F32D8A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Kernelbase" INTERNAL_NAME="Kernelbase" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x52995" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" LINK_DATE="11/30/2012 04:50:30" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/30/2012 04:50:30" EXPORT_NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00002dc195b5162996b04b9e1e7bb25191b6478fcaea" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" /> </EXE> <EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="868352" CHECKSUM="0x69E28698" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xDFFC7" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" LINK_DATE="11/30/2012 04:50:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/30/2012 04:50:29" EXPORT_NAME="KERNEL32.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000ea174348498eaefeba3916a024e5cdd47c0ded68" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" /> </EXE> </DATABASE>
```

I have double checked, rechecked, uninstalled and reinstalled .NET 4.5 on the test computer, and still have the issues. All dll's are registered using regsvr32 in command line. I'm almost certain that I'm missing something silly, but I'm afraid I'm not seeing it. Hoping a fresh pair of eyes would help.

**EDIT**

I've even tried retargeting the program to .NET 4.0, and I get the same XML log, with the exception of instead of being `<Parameter4>4.0.30319.17929</Parameter4>`, I get `<Parameter4>4.0.0.0</Parameter4>`.

Comment: If there is a network connection between your computer and the executing machine, you can try [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) the application.

Comment: @PHeiberg : I tried doing this, but every time I set a breakpoint on my dev machine, I attach to the process running on my test machine, I get "Breakpoint won't be hit. Symbols aren't loaded." I've ensured that I copied all the files from my Debug folder to my test machine.

Comment: I know that frustrating experience all to well. There is a small trouble shooting guide [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/22/troubleshoot-remote-debugging-of-managed-code/). I've also had luck with turning off "Require source files to exactly match the original version".

Comment: I just couldn't believe that it was something so sillyingly simple. But, hey, it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probbably missing some reference. Try catching unhandled exception or use FUSLOGVW to see more info.

Comment: How do you catch an exception before your application enters it's `Main()`? Also, FUSLOGVW showed no results.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if some dlls, that your application use, are missing or cannot be loaded. Check the windows event log, as it may contain meaningful messages from .Net framework runtime.

As a primary suspect, I would check System.Data.SQLite.dll, because it has separate x86 and x64 versions. If you used x64 version on your dev machine, it would not work on x86 OS, and you will need to replace it.

Comment: That would have been my first thought as well, but I got it from NuGet, and it 's the dll that actually supports both x64 and x86.